# Get the 1st element of all the column value and add it into the second column and store the result in a third column in EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

Eg:

I have a list of columns in a excel sheet i want to add the 1st element of each column into the 2nd column and store the result into the third column.
Example:

```
column1 Column2 Column3
Sarah   Broome  Sbroome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write the following formule in column 3

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),B1)`

And you know to copy the same for entire column

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1, 1),"", CONCATENATE(UPPER(LEFT(B1,1)),RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)))
```